# Core Data Fetch Save relationship while inserting entity (simultaneously)

Tags: core-data, insert, many-to-many, entity, relationships

First question here and I've tried a bunch of stuff and can't figure it out.
Core Data with 2 entities with to-many relationship both ways

`A<<---->>B`
`A` entity has name as an attribute, and a relationship `Bs`

First Controller lists all `A` entities and i have a second controller to add `A` entities and I want to have it save a default `B` in its relationship.

In the prepare for segue I have this code:

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"addAEntitySegue"]) {

    AddAEntityViewController *addAEntityViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    addAEntityViewController.delegate = self;
    addAEntityViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    NSManagedObjectContext *addingContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    self.addingManagedObjectContext = addingContext;

    [addingManagedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[[fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator]];

   addAEntityViewController.A = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"A" inManagedObjectContext:addingContext];

    UIBarButtonItem *saveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave
                                                                           target:addAEntityViewController
                                                                               action:@selector(save:)];
    addAEntityViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton;

}
```

In addAEntityViewController i have this to save

```
-(IBAction)save:(id)sender
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"B"                                                    inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@",[defaults objectForKey:@"BDefault"]];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

     //Set the batch size to a suitable number
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
    NSError *error;

    self.A.name = textFieldVal;

    [self.A addBObject:[[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] objectAtIndex:0]];

    NSLog(@"A = %@", self.A.Bs);

    [self.delegate addAEntityViewController:self didFinishWithSave:YES];
}
```

In the `addAEntityViewController` everything saves correctly even the `NSLog(@"A = %@", self.A.Bs);` statement shows the `B`. But when the delegate saves in the First Controller (`AEntityViewController`) it only saves the `A.name` but not the relationship `A.Bs`, I can't figure out what's wrong.

Here's the delegate method:

```
-(void) addAEntityViewController:self didFinishWithSave:YES{
if (save) {
    NSLog(@"saveworkouts");

    NSError *error;
    if (![addingManagedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);  // Fail
    }
}

// release the adding managed object context
self.addingManagedObjectContext = nil;
}
```

Like I said it saves the `A` entity but not the relationship to `B` even though the relationship to `B` saved correctly in the `addAEntityViewController` (the second View). An `NSLOg` of `A.Bs` is null.

Answer (score 0):

First I believe that this line:
`addAEntityViewController = self.managedObjectContext;`
should be:
`addAEntityViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;`

but that would also be wrong.
it should be getting the `addingContext` you created afterwards:
`addAEntityViewController.managedObjectContext = addingContext;`

I'm a bit surprised that your app didn't crash, as you are mixing managed objects from 2 different contexts.

Comment: You are still using the wrong context in `addAEntityViewController` it should be set to `addingContext` (the context entity A was created in)

Comment: The A entity is set in the managedObjectContext but not inserted until the delegate inserts it in the addingContext, which should be fine. The A.name gets saved no problem. It's the A.Bs relationship that doesn't get inserted also. I have a feeling that relationships don't get inserted until the entity is saved.

Comment: This is what i'm trying to make clear. The Bs entity are fetched in the `managedObjectContext` of the first view controller. to prove that use the quick fix: instead of `[self.A addBObject:[[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] objectAtIndex:0]];` use `[self.A addBObject:[[self.A.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] objectAtIndex:0]];`